# Failed schema migration with Django South: what should I do?

Tags: mysql, django, django-south

I'm using Django with MySQL. I installed South and am trying to migrate my application from one schema to another. However when I run `$ python manage.py migrate catalog` I get the following error:

```
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_initial.
 > catalog:0003_initial
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   = DROP TABLE `categories` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `product_shapes` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `materials` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `style` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `products` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `products_shape` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `products_materials` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `products_style` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `products_categories` CASCADE; []

 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS.
```

Is there any way I can migrate without having to drop these tables. I have a feeling if I drop the tables I'll end up losing the data I'm trying to save.

EDIT:

I believe this is the main error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'categories' already exists")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't drop these tables if they have data in them that you want to save.

It's hard to offer any more specific help without seeing the actual error, which should follow the message you quoted.